# How to remove shower drain

Tags: drain, bathtub

My shower drain is clogged.  I want to open the drain cover, but I can't get it off (see picture of drain cover)[image: drain]

How should this be opened:  prying it off or unscrewing it?

Regards,

**UPDATE**

This words on the cover are: "florestone madera ca"

Comment: As a general rule for clogged drains, I'd look for a clean out access to the drain line a little further down, probably sticking out the other side of the wall,  maybe under a counter top. As a general rule for opening a shower drain, try turning it first before yanking or prying. As a general rule of plumbing, be mentally prepared for 'oh, now I have to replace these bits. '

Comment: can't quite make out what it says on the cover ..... why did you think that the writing on the cover is not important?  .... always include as much info as you can .... please update your question ...... do not add info to comments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lettering on the drain cover leads to a number of similar (but not exactly the same) products all over the 'net. What is consistent about this particular company's line of products is that the words "snap-in" appear frequently.

[image: drain cover]

The image above differs from yours in that your "tab" area is much thinner and does not show clearly any tabs. If you are able to shine light into the area of the slots and are able to see tabs, one can expect that it too is a snap-in cover.

Even a rather comprehensive installation document for plumbing a Florestone shower pan includes nothing about the drain cover. This is consistent with one being able to see the removed cover and recognizing that it is a snap-in type. In place, it's not so easy to determine that aspect.

Image courtesy of [Decour Glamour](https://www.decorglamour.com/westbrass-d3191-50.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIiuOIpNWi3QIVjVcNCh38dAppEAQYBSABEgLcZvD_BwE) web page.

Comment: The answer seems to stop a bit short of answering the actual question. If it is a snap-in type, how do you remove it?

Comment: @Moyli - Pull it straight out with force. I'd have thought that was fairly obvious personally.

Comment: The problem with removing these covers is that they have to be tight enough to make a waterproof seal with the floor covering - and it the shower was installed carelessly, some adhesive from laying the floor will have got into the wrong place and be gluing down the drain cover. Be prepared for the fact that removing the existing cover will destroy it!

Comment: " Pull it straight out with force" - but unless you have a trained octopus which can attach its suckers to the cover, there is nothing that you can get hold of to pull ;)

Comment: @alephzero a very cool and innovative product by the name of "pliers" might be of use here.

Comment: @alephzero Needlenose pliers to grip the bit between two of the holes. Alternatively, you can find screws or bolts that are a little larger than the holes, screw them into the holes, and pull on them. If you've only got one, put it in the middle, or else place it closest to a tab, pull to disengage that tab, and move it round to the next one until they're all free. Otherwise, put two in the holes closest to two opposing tabs. The benefit of using two, besides spreading the force so you're less likely to damage the cover, is that it also lets you try twisting it to see if that helps.

Comment: @anaximander that last comment might do well as an answer...

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to pull it with two hex keys. It came off very easily

Answer (score 1):

If it says "Florestone Madera CA" just put something in the holes, pull, and it pops right up.  If you want, you can put two dowels or screw drivers with round shanks in the holes and put another long screw driver parallel with the floor across them, as leverage, and turn the drain to break it loose.  Just has hair in drain and slows the water draining out.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cover EXACTLY like yours. Mine just lifted right up. Not sure if there was *supposed* to be some kind of sealant, but it would not surprise me that the installers "forgot".

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It seems like the oblong holes indicates that a special tool is needed to unscrew it, so I would attempt to unscrew it by improvising a tool in those oblong slots. Frank

Comment: The oblong holes are where the friction tabs are stamped.  They are not particular to the cover's removal.  The cover is not "unscrewed" but rather simply lifted straight up with an appropriate tool (small hook-like device) or by prying gently with a small diameter screwdriver or similar.